# How to wait for API response in the nested subscription before executing next line of code

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I have a method that should return me a boolean value, the problem is that this is asynchronus and I want to avoid race condition..

So I have some method for example:

```
someMethod(data: any): boolean{
 let isOccupied = false;
 firstValueFrom(this.checkIfOccupied('102')).then(toilet=> isOccupied = toilet.name === data.name);
 this.someObject.isOccupied = isOccupied;
 return isOccupied;
}
```

So before I proceed to the line with `this.someObject...` I want to wait for things that are happening inside of `then(  )`

And the `checkIfOccupied` looks like this:

```
  checkIfOccupied(toiletName: string): Observable<Toilet> {
    return this.store$
      .select(selectAlarmsForToilet(toiletName))
      .pipe(
        filter(res => !!res),
        take(1),
        switchMap((alarms: AlarmsObject[]) => {
          alarms.forEach(alarm => {
            if (Object.keys(alarm)[0].includes('occupied')) {
              const toiletId  = this.getToiletIdFromAlarm(toiletName, alarm); <= this method only finds needed ID
              if (toiletId ) {
                return this.toiletService.getToiletForId(toiletId ); <= this is API call
              }
            }
          });
          return of({} as SomeObject);
        }));
  }
```

I have tried to make it async and then use await in the `someMethod` but it doesn't work. Probably I made some mistake in the code (I dont want to make `someMethod` async - is it even possible?)

Answer (score 0):

You are very close in your thinking.

Consider the words you stated, which I will paraphase:

"Before I proceed to the next line, I want to wait for something"

So change your code like so:

```
async someMethod(data: any): Promise<boolean>{
 let isOccupied = false;
 data = await firstValueFrom(this.checkIfOccupied('102'));
 this.someObject.isOccupied = toilet.name === data.name;
 return toilet.name === data.name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Arrays.prototype.forEach inside your switchMap, which does not know anything about asynchronousity.

To keep up with race conditions, you can use the forkJoin Operator, which waits for Observables in arrays to complete such as:

```
someMethod(data: any): boolean {
    let isOccupied = false;
    firstValueFrom(this.checkIfOccupied('102')).then(toilet => isOccupied = 
       toilet.name === data.name);
    this.someObject.isOccupied = isOccupied;
    return isOccupied;
  }

  checkIfOccupied(toiletName: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.store$
      .select(selectAlarmsForToilet(toiletName))
      .pipe(
        filter(res => !!res),
        take(1),
        switchMap((alarms: AlarmsObject[]) => {
          return alarms.length ? forkJoin(alarms
          .filter(alarm => Object.keys(alarm)[0].includes('occupied'))
          .map((alarm: any) => this.getToiletIdFromAlarm(toiletName, alarm))
          .filter(toiletId => !!toiledId)
          .map((toiletId: any) => {
           return this.toiletService.getToiletForId(toiletId); // api call
            })) : of([]);
        }));
  }
```

Comment: But I have `return` in my forEach, it should finish iterating over the array I guess..